# Why the 'fetch function' automatically call the 'parse function' on backbone.js collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to parse my json file into Backbone collection and model as like below.

This is .json file

```
[
{
    "type": "rect",
    "x": 10,
    "y": 10,
    "w": 100,
    "h": 100,
    "color": "red"
},
{
    "type": "arc",
    "x": 210,
    "y": 20,
    "w": 200,
    "h": 150,
    "color": "blue"
}
]
```

And I also have .html  file as like below.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var JSONModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

        var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : JSONModel,
            url : 'profiles.json',
            initialize : function() {
                alert("init");
            },
            parse : function(response) {

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var tmpModel = new JSONModel();
                    tmpModel.set({
                        type : response[i].type,
                        x : response[i].x,
                        y : response[i].y,
                        w : response[i].w,
                        h : response[i].h,
                        color : response[i].color
                    });
                    this.add(tmpModel);
                    alert("inserting" + i);
                }

                return response;
            }

        });

        var collection = new MyCollection();
        collection.fetch();
        alert(collection.length);


    });
</script>
```

---

Q.

1.In this code, why fetch function call parse function?

2.Is there any other function which is called from fetch function?

3.Do you think how can I fix this code to get the json object? I cannot get the 'collection.length' in this code.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at my comments below for your question:

**1**. In this code, why fetch function call parse function?

**Ans:** While extending `Backbone.Collection` you have overridden the `parse` callback function and `Backbone` internally calls the `parse` function whenever we try to `fetch` the collection. This is the standard call. I don't think you have to Or can change this behavior.

**2**.  Is there any other function which is called from fetch function?

**Ans:** As far as I know I don't think any other callback function is getting called while calling `fetch`. Why you are looking for it? What is your requirement for this point? Any specific reason?

**3**. Do you think how can I fix this code to get the json object? I cannot get the 'collection.length' in this code.

**Ans:** You will have to wait till the time we receive the data and hence we need to add `success` handler in following way:

```
collection.fetch({
  success: function(collection){
    // Callback triggered only after receiving the data.
    console.log(collection.length); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second question was little bit ambiguous, sorry. As you told, fetch calls parse internally. And I meant "Is there any other function like parse which is called from fetch function".

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting the expected length is that `fetch()` is asynchronous. You need to check for the length once the promise is resolved (fetch is done).

All you need to do is this:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: JSONModel,
  url: 'profiles.json',
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("init");
  }
});

var collection = new MyCollection();
collection.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response) {
    console.log(collection.length);
  }
});
```

If you define a `parse` method, backbone will execute it before updating the model and executing other callbacks (*passed in the options*), this is required only if you want to modify the fetched data before processing it further (updating the model/collection, passing to callbacks etc).

For example, assume your `.json` contains the following:

```
{
 "someKey": "some Info",
 "data": [{
  "type": "rect",
  "x": 10,
  "y": 10,
  "w": 100,
  "h": 100,
  "color": "red"
 },
 {
  "type": "arc",
  "x": 210,
  "y": 20,
  "w": 200,
  "h": 150,
  "color": "blue"
 }]
}
```

Then you'd want to parse this and return the actual array like:

```
parse: function(response){
  console.log(response.someKey); // do somethig with this if required
  return response.data;
}
```

In your case, the `.json` contains an array of objects, backbone will parse each object in the array into a model of the specified type and add it in your collection. There is no need to specify a `parse` method.

And yes, there are other methods that gets called internally, for example `sync`, `toJSON` etc. each of them has their own duty (*and can be overridden*) which is given in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally understand this problem because of you! It was helpful so much!!

Comment: Can I just add the success function in the MyCollection, tough?